# How to rotate a jpeg file from HTML input field and save it as a base64 string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular and taking in a HTML image file and i need to rotate the image based on the EXIF data which i have access to. I am currently just saving it as a base 64 string but i need to rotate it CLIENT SIDE.

Comment: Can't you use CSS like `transform: rotateZ(25deg);`? Example: https://codepen.io/manelgarcia/pen/zjgLeR

Comment: But that wouldn't help saving it rotated, I believe.

Comment: CSS won't help. It doesn't change the file structure

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you should follow:

- first get the image from input
- then write the image on Canvas
- rotate the canvas
- export the image

you can also see my working example of this here: [rotate image](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rotate-image-base64)

**do not forget to run this in a server(ex: [serve module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)) for canvas security concerns**

hope it help.